# javascript regex for numbers now accepts dots and slashes

Tags: javascript

The below javascript with its regex code has been developed and tested, it accepts numbers  but it also accepts unwanted items like '/' and dot (.) and other items instead of only numbers like 45 33 78 89.  I guess the fault is from my regex expression.

```
function validtn (textbox) { 
    textbox.value = textbox.value.replace(/[^\0-9]/ig, "");
}

<input type="text" onKeyUp="validtn(this);" />
```

I only want numbers nothing else....

Answer (score 2):

For anything other than digits you can use the following, i.e. without the slash (unsure as to why you have that there).  Slashes `\` are required only to escape certain characters.

```
textbox.value.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, "");
```

Please reference [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for details.

Comment: you might also try http://jsregex.rcode5.com where you can try out your regex online - then when you get it working, stick it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` in your regex actually escaping the `0` character so it should be just this `/[^0-9]/ig`

Comment: ? Escaping characters works forwards, not backwards. (The backslash *is* most likely causing the problem, though. Perhaps it gets interpreted as a literal character `null` -- that would explain allowing everything up to '9', which happens to include the slash, the period, and the space.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
textbox.value.replace(/\D+/g, '')
// \d : digit
// \D : non-digit
```